# Unable to load executing assembly into new AppDomain, FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, appdomain

I am trying to host a text template class proxy inside a new AppDomain.

I have some old scripting code that does something similar, that contains this working code:

```
_ScriptAppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(scriptDomainFriendlyName);
_ScriptProxy = (IScriptEngineProxy)_ScriptAppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
    "LVK.Scripting.ScriptEngineProxy");
```

However, when I try this with my new class, with the following

```
_TemplateDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(templateDomainFriendlyName);
_TemplateProxy = (ITemplateProxy)_TemplateDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
    "TextTemplate.TemplateProxy");
```

I just get "FileNotFoundException", with the following details:

> Could not load file or assembly 'TextTemplate, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bb70a2e62a722ace' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What am I missing?

Basically, I have a Template class in the TextTemplate namespace (and assembly), which tries to load a TemplateProxy class (descending from MarshalByRefObject) into the new appdomain, but it appears my main assembly is not loaded into this domain.

This works if I use the older code, but not with this new one, but I can't spot the difference.

Here's some more details:

- Assembly is not registered with the GAC (neither was the old one, which works)
- I have not overridden any AssemblyResolve event (neither did the old one, which works)

I'm not averse to handling the AssemblyResolve event, if that is what is needed. I just found it odd that my old code worked, and this didn't.

Comment: did you add code for assembly resolving? Maybe that could help you to get more details.

Comment: Is TextTemplate assembly deployed to GAC?

Comment: @Sam, no, it isn't, but neither was the old assembly.

Comment: @LexRema, no, I did not, I didn't have it in the old assembly either. Do I need to override the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event?

Comment: it can provide you with info what assembly it is searching now. You can resolve it by passing executing. Your code seems not to have any "underwater stones". But who knows what's the reason.

Comment: I'll see if I can't make a simple test program that demonstrates the problem and post that.

Comment: I think the key point in the exception message is "or one of its dependencies". Can you check availability of dependencies of the TextTemplate assembly?

Comment: Could the assembly name be wrong, is it in the same executing assembly?  Does `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly` or `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly` work in place of `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly`?

Comment: Does your TextTemplate.TemplateProxy reference some other assemblies? I'd agry with Sam B.

Comment: No, the only two references in my main assembly here is System and System.Core.

Comment: Ah, it appears that the problem is with TestDriven.Net and LINQPad, they seem to load the assemblies in a funky way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assumying your assembly is in the same directory as your current application base, try specifying Application Base:

```
        AppDomain.CreateDomain(templateDomainFriendlyName, null,
            new AppDomainSetup
            {
                ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase
            });
```

Comment: Well, with that, that part of the code ran through without problems, but now I get "Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found."

Comment: In the code that compiles my template. I tried reducing everything down to a small program, but this worked, so I'll try to expand it back up to see where the problem is.

Comment: This was indeed the problem, the compiler error was something completely different.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know what you are doing, the best way to create a new domain is to copy all settings from the current one, like this:

```
        var newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("NAME", 
                        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence,
                        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation);
```

I had similar issues, and making a copy resolved them for me